# How to combine two logistic regression models trained on different set of data?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

My data has a **hierarchy structure** - meaning that there is an **N class at level 1 and an M class at level M**. After training both models separately with a different set of data (both are Logistic regression but can be changed) I want to predict to **N + M classes**.

Currently, I am solving it **by collecting all** data before training and adding examples from level 2 to level 1 results in (N + 1) classes (+ 1 meaning all examples from level 2) and if the model at level 1 predicts that "+1" class then a send the query to the second model. But collecting the examples before training is costly and also the training set is unbalanced after collecting. Pseudocode:

```
clf1 = LogisticRegression()
clf1.fit(X1 + X2, Y1 + ["ID of +1 class"] * len(Y2))
clf2 = LogisticRegression()
clf2.fit(X2, Y2)
if cl1.predict(X_test_example) == ["ID of +1 class"]:
    clf2.precict(X_test_example)
```

But I need to preserve this hierarchical structure so the merging the two models directly is not possible. Is there a way to combine two outputs of classification models (in a form of the probability distribution) to get meaningful output are avoid problems with the overconfidence of models? Pseudocode:

```
clf1 = LogisticRegression()
clf1.fit(X1, Y1)
clf2 = LogisticRegression()
clf2.fit(X2, Y2)
combined_clf = clf1 + clf2
```